# difference between two tar commands

Tags: tar

i want to tar the contents inside **/some/directory/** and this directory has lots of files and other sub directories in it.

what is the actual difference between the below tar commands, i noticed the latter command contains more files in the tar archive compared to the first one.

i compared by using `tar -tvf | wc -l` on each archive

```
cd /some/directory/
tar -cvf /tmp/directory.tar *
```

compared to

```
tar -cvf /tmp/directory.tar -C /some/directory/ .
```

Comment: If I get it right  `*` is not including files starting with a dot like `.bashrc` while `.` is including all files in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first command will `tar` all files inside `/some/directory` recursively where the pattern `*` matches. These are generally all non-hidden files. If you're using `bash`, you need to enable the `dotglob` shell option with `shopt -s dotglob` to also match hidden files before running the command.

The second command changes the directory to `/some/directory` and includes the current directory `.` and all files including hidden files inside it. It also adds `./` as parent directory to the archive. You can see this additional folder with `tar tf /tmp/directory.tar`, but there is no difference to the first command on extraction (besides missing hidden files and that all files in the second archive are prefixed with the relative path `./`)